# What is the 'White Rock' in Greek mythology?

Tags: greek, underworld

I just found this term, White Rock, or Leucas, while reading about the Underworld [here](http://www.maicar.com/GML/Underworld.html).

> As men and women die, Hermes leads their souls to the Underworld, past the streams of Oceanus, past the White Rock (Leucas), past the Gates of the Sun and the Land of Dreams, until they reach the Asphodel Fields, where the spirits dwell living the flavourless existence of a shadow or phantom.

What does the White Rock mean or symbolize? Is it just a land mark in the Underworld, or does it have some special significance?

Answer (score 3):

In the Odyssey:

πὰρ δ’ ἴσαν Ὠκεανοῦ τε ῥοὰς καὶ **Λευκάδα πέτρην**
ἠδὲ παρ’ Ἠελίοιο πύλας καὶ δῆμον ὀνείρων

> And they passed by the streams of Okeanos and the White Rock (the original says 
>   **Leukàs Pétrā**) and past the Gates of the Sun and the District of Dreams.

Leukas is the name of a Greek Island in the Ionian sea. Nowadays it is called [Lefkada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefkada).

The likelihood the White Rock refers to this island is corroborated by other texts, like [Menander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menander)'s Leukadia (The Girl from Leukas):

οὗ δὴ λέγεται πρώτη Σαπφὼ
τὸν ὑπέρκομπον θηρῶσα Φάον’
οἰστρῶντι πόθῳ ῥῖψαι πέτρας
ἀπὸ τηλεφανοῦς. ἀλλὰ κατ’εὐχὴν
σήν, δέσποτ’ ἄναξ, εὐφημείσθω
τέμενος πέρι Λευκάδος ἀκτῆς

> where they say that Sappho was the first, hunting down the proud
>   Phaon, to throw herself, in her goading desire, from **the rock that shines from afar**.
>   But now, in accordance with your sacred utterance,
>   lord king, let there be silence throughout the sacred precinct of the
>   head-land of Leukas.

Also in [Anacreon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacreon):

ἀρθεὶς δηὖτ’ ἀπὸ **Λευκάδος

πέτρης** ἐς πολιὸν κῦμα κολυμβῶ μεθύων ἔρωτι

> One more time taking off in the air, down from the **White Rock** into
>   the dark waves do I dive, intoxicated with lust.

and [Euripides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides)' Cyclops:

ὡς ἐκπιεῖν γ’ ἂν κύλικα μαινοίμην μίαν
πάντων Κυκλώπων <μὴ> ἀντιδοὺς βοσκήματα
ῥῖψαί τ’ ἐς ἅλμην **Λευκάδος πέτρας** ἄπο
ἅπαξ μεθυσθεὶς καταβαλών τε τὰς ὄφρυς.
ὡς ὅς γε πίνων μὴ γέγηθε μαίνεται

> I would be crazy not to give all the herds of the Cyclopes in return
>   for drinking one cup [of that wine] and throw myself from the **white rock**
>   into the brine, once I am intoxicated, with eyebrows relaxed.
>   Whoever is not happy when he drinks is crazy.